# Partition Sorting issue

Tags: c++

I am trying to do a quick sorting. But I have some problem with it. It was supposed to change this array:

```
{ 1,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,10 }
```

When it receives the arguments `left = 0, right = 4 and pivotIndex = 2`, to this one:

```
{ 7,6,1,8,9,5,4,3,2,10 }
```

But it is actually changing the array to this one:

```
{ 1,6,7,8,9,5,4,3,2,10 }
```

I also get this problem if I try to partition this array:

```
{ 7,6,1,8,9,5,4,3,2,10 }
```

with arguments `right = 9, left = 4 and pivotIndex = 2`, to this array:

```
{ 7,6,1,8,9,2,3,5,4,10 }
```

I am actually changing to this array:

```
{ 7,6,1,8,9,2,3,10,5,4 }
```

Code:

```
int QS::partition(int left, int right, int pivotIndex)
{

    if (my_array == NULL)
        return -1;
    if (elements <= 0 || capacity <= 0)
        return -1;
    if (left < 0 || right < 0)
        return -1;
    else if (right - left <= 1)
        return -1;
    if (right > elements - 1)
        return -1;
    if (!(pivotIndex <= right) || !(pivotIndex >= left))
        return -1;
    int first = pivotIndex;
    int last;
    if (first == right)
       last = left;
    else
       last = right;
    int up = first + 1;
    int down = last - 1;

    do{
        while (!(up != last - 1) || !(my_array[up] <= my_array[first]))
            up++;
        while (!(my_array[down] > my_array[first]) || !(down != first))
            down--;
        if (up < down)
            swap(up, down);
    } while (up < down);

    swap(first, down);


    return down;
}
```

I was told to use this algorithm:

[image]

But I could not make it work with this algorithm, the closest I got to the result I was told to get, was with the code I am showing you guys.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Your "expected" results look unexpected to me. In particular, `left > right` should leave the array unmodified, and in the first one your result is exactly what one would expect (swap 6 and 9, then swap 7 and 8.) Where did you get them from?

Comment: Yeah, I know right? It is for a class. They did not give instructions, only this algorithm and it does not work. They are asking for this "expected results" but it does not work >< I am working on it for 20 hours now

Comment: Sorry, I misread a little – if you implement that algorithm correctly, you should get the first expected result (step 9 swaps 7 and 1).

Comment: I wasn't able to write the algorithm properly than. :( I don't have the code I wrote here. Can you send me an email so I can send you what I have when I get home? Archiza@hotmail.com

Comment: It's pretty straightforward to translate that to C++; you can do it line-by-line. (Don't fall into the trap of trying to fix bugs by adding more code. It's usually much better to start over.)

Comment: So, I just edited my code to the one I wrote before. I tried to write this algorithm for the fifth time now. Does it look right? @molbdnilo

Comment: I was getting into an infinite loop with this code

Comment: Plss haha thank you very much for your help so far.

Comment: "Until A or B" means "While not A *and* not B". (Look up *DeMorgan's laws* when you get the time.

Comment: Hm. Sounds good. I am going to make some tests when I get home